# QComboBox getting wrong index

Tags: pyqt5, qcombobox

I have this combobox.

```
 klients = qtw.QComboBox(self)
 klients.insertItem(5, "x")
 klients.insertItem(19, "y")
```

when I later write this code in button clicked event:

```
print(klients.currentIndex())
```

It prints 0 or 1 instead of 5 or 19. How can I achieve it prints 5 or 19?

Comment: why would you like to have only 5 and 19 index instead of 0 and 1 ? If you need these values maybe you could use `void QComboBox::insertItem(int index, const QString &text, const QVariant &userData = QVariant())` and pass that 5/19 on userData param

Comment: @Megasa3 Because I need to query database with index 5 or 19.

Comment: And using the option I told you? You can access that info later with currentData or itemData methods instead of currentIndex

Comment: @Megasa3 Could you please write it in Python?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Just know about Qt with C++ and wanted to help but it has to be something like  `klients.insertItem(0, "x", 5);` and access it with something like  `value =klients.itemData(klients.currentIndex());`

Comment: I see you acepted the answer of musicamante which is the same I was saying so I guess it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QComboBox item management works just like a list: after creating a new list, doing `list.insert(5, "x")` will add "x" at the *first* index, which is quite obvious, since the list is empty.

If you want to have internal reference of custom data, then use the `userData` argument of [`addItem()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#addItem):

```
klients.addItem("x", 5)
klients.addItem("y", 19)
```

and then retrieve it with [`currentData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentData-prop):

```
data = klients.currentData()
# equivalent to
data = klients.itemData(klients.currentIndex())
```